# How to authenticate itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url= Angular+Spring Boot

Tags: java, ios, angular, manifest

I'm working on an app that is used to distribute apps to users in my company. The problem comes to not know how to authenticate the request to the backend of the manifest of the ios app so that the authenticated user can download it. The manifest and ipa are in a MySQL database and i want to get it by a angular+spring boot request. The backend give 401 error code.

If i set the request without authorization, i can install without problem, but i need to authorize the request

The html code looks as:

```
<ion-button [href]="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=myurl.com/download.ipa"> Download</ion-button>
```

I tried of make an angular request but the url of the file is not valid

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.